# How to add program to Windows startup

Tags: winapi, cmd

I want that, when my program runs, it adds itself to Windows startup (if it doesn't exist there).

I tried this:

```
REG ADD HKLM\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Run /v mycompany /d C:\ProgramFiles\mycompany\demo.exe /f
```

I also tried to copy the shortcut of the program to C:\ProgramData\Microsoft\Windows\Start Menu\Programs\StartUp

But, I need administrator privileges for both. What should I do?

Comment: Add a shortcut to the *user's* Startup folder, not the global one. Avoid the registry altogether.

Comment: But then you have have to install it separately for every user on the machine.  If you want it to run for all users, HKLM and the AllUsers profile are the correct way to go.

Answer (score 1):

You can change to:

```
REG ADD HKCU\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Run /v mycompany /d C:\ProgramFiles\mycompany\demo.exe /f
```

Which should be able to write to that part of the registry

The HKLM key has read access for standard users by default.  Whereas the HKCU key has write access for the currently logged in user.

If you want the program to run for all users then you could run a setup program  with administrator privileges.  Usually, you would run installers as administrator or equivalent on Windows.

Answer (score 1):

> I need administrator privileges for both. What should I do?

If you want your app to run for all users with a single installation, you need to install it as an admin so you can update the global users profile.  So either make a separate installer that runs with admin rights, or make your app run an elevated copy of itself so it can gain temporary admin rights when it needs to access the global profile.

The only way to avoid that is to have each user run the app separately so it can install itself into each individual user's profile.  You don't need admin rights for that.